# on branched covers

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Consider a branched cover $f:M\to N$ with branch set $A\subset M$ and $B\subset N$. In Rolfsen's book Knots and Links, it is assumed as part of the definition of a branched cover  that the dimension of $A$ (or $B$) is 2 less than that of $M$ (or N). Is this condition always necessary in order to have a branched cover?

Comment: No; a (topological) branched cover is just a map $M\to N$ that's a covering map off a nohwere-dense set. In particular, it's well-defined for $1$-manifolds; take, for example, the obvious map $S^1 \vee \dots \vee S^1 \to S^1$.

Comment: @anomaly: I think the point is that if the branched cover is nontrivial $M$ will not be a manifold unless the branch set is codimension 2. This is at the very least true for the branched covers of links (embedded disjoint copies of $S^k$) in $S^n$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I don't have my copy of Rolfson with me at the moment, but that would make sense.