# Possible dimension of branch locus in definition of finite cover of varieties/manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, definition

Given a finite morphism of (complex) varieties $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ ($\dim Y \ge 2$), is the branch locus $B \subset Y$ always a divisor in $Y$?
There seem to be differing accounts from different questions on this site ([on branched covers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397504/on-branched-covers) and [branch locus of $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711028/branch-locus-of-f-x-longrightarrow-y-morphism)) possibly depending on smoothness assumptions/whether the objects involved actually define manifolds when we're working over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The Rolfsen reference is in the real category, hence not quite germane. But the upshot is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first point out a difference in terminology: different people use "branch locus" to refer to either the set in $X$ where $f$ is ramified (I usually call this the ramified locus) or the image of this under the map $f$ (this is what I usually consider the branch locus). Unfortunately, it seems like these terms are not standardized in the literature - the result I'll present below speaks of the branch locus in the first way, i.e. on $X$.

---

The big result in this area is called the "purity of the branch locus". This was originally proven by Zariski and Nagata in 1958 ([On the purity of the branch locus of algebraic functions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC534562/) by Zariski, and [Remarks on a paper of Zariski on the purity of the branch locus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC534563/) by Nagata). For better or worse, these papers were mostly written in the old style which I find a bit hard to read. A more modern expose is given in the Stacks Project as [tag 0BMB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMB):

> **Lemma**. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of locally noetherian schemes. Let $x\in X$ and set $y=f(x)$. Assume
>
> 1. $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is normal,
> 2. $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is regular,
> 3. $f$ is quasi-finite at $x$,
> 4. $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \dim \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \geq 1$,
> 5. for specializations $x'\rightsquigarrow x$ with $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x'}=1$ our $f$ is unramified at $x'$.
>
> Then $f$ is etale at $x$.

In your case, we can use this to arrive at the following, where I use "variety" to mean "scheme of finite type":

**Lemma**. Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a map of varieties over $\Bbb C$. If $X$ is normal, $Y$ is regular, and $f$ is finite, then the branch locus is of pure codimension one (i.e. a divisor) inside $Y$.

To prove this, apply the lemma above, and then note that a finite surjective morphism preserves dimensions.

Removing either the assumption that $X$ is normal or $Y$ is regular should lead to counterexamples, but I don't have them immediately on hand for you. If you're interested in them, please leave a comment and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: This was very helpful since I had been wondering if what I expected was specific to the algebraic category. I had the feeling that regularity assumptions had to do with counterexamples, but couldn't find concrete examples. It would be nice to see what would be possible.